# Populate cells with HTML in Grid.js

Tags: javascript, gridjs

How can I populate cells with HTML content in [Grid.js](https://gridjs.io)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the `html` function first:

```js
import { Grid, html } from "gridjs";
```

then use that in `formatter` function or directly in `data`:

```js
const grid = new Grid({
  columns: [
      { 
        name: 'Name',
        formatter: (cell) => html(`<b>${cell}</b>`)
      },
      'Email',
      { 
        name: 'Actions',
        formatter: (_, row) => html(`<a href='mailto:${row.cells[1].data}'>Email</a>`)
      },
   ],
  data: Array(5).fill().map(x => [
    faker.name.findName(),
    faker.internet.email(),
    null
  ])
});
```

also check out https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/html-cells

Comment: how do you do this when you aren't using a javascript framework?

Comment: @JakeMcAllister my answer is not framework specific. You can still use that answer without any JS frameworks.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani
how to use this via vanilla JS directly via HTML markup?
how do I get the "html" function to work?

FYI,
I'm using CDN to load the gridjs

Comment: What if I need to put two buttons with on click events for edit or delete for example ? I tried this method and it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using gridjs CDN implementation via browser,
I can use formatter by accessing the html function via gridjs namespace as per below

```
    {
        name: "Action",
        formatter: (cell) => {
            return gridjs.html(`<a href="">update</a>`)
            // return `Update button`
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it just says gridjs is undefined when importing from cdn

Answer (score 2):

For me, I set the script type "text/javascript" to "module".
And then I can use "import" like this =>

```
<script type="module">
        import {
            Grid,
            html
        } from "/Scripts/gridjs.production.es.min.js";
        
        //then use html with formatter

        {
           name: "Actions",
           formatter: (cell) => {
           return html(`<a data-id=${cell} href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</a>`)
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the data received with a service or something else and then pass it in html ;)

```
import { Grid, html } from "gridjs";

const columns = [
        {
            id: 'difficulty',
            name: 'Difficulté',
            formatter: (cell) => {
                const difficultyConverter = new DifficultyConverter()
                const displayedDifficultyResults = difficultyConverter.getNameAndAssociatedClassName(cell, null)

                return html(`<span class='badge ${displayedDifficultyResults.originClassToAdd}--active'>${displayedDifficultyResults.originName}</span>`)
            }
        },
        {
            id: 'community_difficulty',
            name: 'Communauté',
            formatter: (cell) => {
                const difficultyConverter = new DifficultyConverter()
                const displayedDifficultyResults = difficultyConverter.getNameAndAssociatedClassName(cell, null)

                return html(`<span class='badge ${displayedDifficultyResults.originClassToAdd}--active'>${displayedDifficultyResults.originName}</span>`)
            }
        },
]
```